# Glua error "attempt to call method 'GetPlayerVisible' (a nil value)"

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I personally don't know how a built in function can be indexed as "nil" butthis error appeared and it haulted my nextbot's movement. heres my code that is causing this

```lua
if (!self:GetPlayerVisible() and chasing_timer > chasing_time) then
           self.stopchasing = true
           self.enraged = false
           print("Chase stopped")
           print("Increasing escaped chases count, new:", self.escapedchases)
           self.escapedchases = self.escapedchases + 1
       end
```

I tried replacing the "!" with "not" but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what self is but that table does not contain an element GetPlayerVisible. Hece you may not call it. Calling nil values doesn't make sense.

Ask yourself why you think this function exists. Typical reasons are typos, indexing the wrong table or not having implemented a function yet.

To avoid this error you basically have two options. Make sure you call something that exists, or don't call it.

Comment: This version of lua is run in garry's mod. "self" means the entity that is running the script and the thing that confuses me is that "GetPlayerVisible" is a build in garry's mod function. it detects if the player can see the entity...

Comment: well whatever table self refers to it does not have a field "GetPlayerVisible". where do you have this function name from? I cannot find it in the documentation https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/   so what makes you think this is an official function?    what entity would that be btw?

Comment: i fixed it. you're right. "GetPlayerVisible" isn't in the wiki. for some reason the code worked until now. i fixed it by actually defining getplayervisible with "self:Visible(self:GetEnemy)."